# How to modify the textField in JasperReports using Java

Tags: api, jasper-reports, textfield

I have created a `textField` in `JasperReports`. Using Java how do i modify the `textField` properties like width, postion etc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down the design of your report template into parts which will be static (not as a static content but a static design) and the dynamic one.

Use subreports to externalize static parts of the template.

JasperReports allows dynamic creation of report templates. Compose final report template from existing subreports adding and modifying on the fly just the parts that are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

we can change the textfield properties dynamically through JRTextField class.... Refer http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html for API and its methods